# android bundle wont carry over

Tags: android, database, bundle

Hello I am new to this site also kinda new to android programming...

Every time I click the button to go to next activity I get a force close. I know the activity works because I commented out the bundles.. anyone know What I am doing wrong?

```
// click button on 1st activity

    Intent iCreate = new 
Intent("silver.asw.charactersheet.CREATECHARACTER");
        iCreate.putExtra("cname",item);
        startActivity(iCreate);

// on item select
item = spin.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
// spinner is being populated by sql database


// 2nd activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.character);
    TextView character = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvViewCharacter);

    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String item = b.getString("cname");
    character.setText(item);
}
```

Also, I dont have any warnings or cant check my logcat as I am using AIDE which is an android app ide. (I have tested this code on my computer before I left home, same issue.)

Comment: when do you do this `item = spin.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`? before or after `startActivity(iCreate);`?

Comment: After, in the onitemselected method

Comment: I don't know, it seems you are getting `null` for `String item = b.getString("cname");`. have you checked the value of `item` when `iCreate.putExtra("cname",item);`?

Comment: BTW: You can check the logcat output in AIDE. It's in the menu.

Comment: found the logcat, thanks. But it seems to be pulling in information from every activity.. anyway i can filter it for ONLY the app i'm working on?

Answer (score 0):

you are not putting any bundle in intent but trying receiving in second activity.use this way:

```
// 1nd activity
item = spin.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("cname", item);
iCreate.putExtras(bundle);

// 2nd activity

 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String name = bundle.getString("cname");
```

Comment: Position is part of onItemSelected function. How can i get the selected items position?

Comment: if starting activity outside from onItemSelected  store value somewhere then read it.try `public static String item="";`

Comment: k so public static .... allowed me to solve the initial problem... or rather, a work around.. the above  code was a troubleshoot of a bigger code. I will post the bigger code when i get home, as im still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your onClick function is but try something like this
Ex.

initialize button

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        //start activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, StartPage.class));

        }}
```

Comment: onClick is set where the intent is.. the intent is part.of the switch/case inside the onclick method. The "item" var is part of tge onitemselected method

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

replace the above line with below in first activity

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();



Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();//from 2 activity you can call as it no need to have this
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second activity, use

```
String item = getIntent().getStringExtra("cname");
```

instead of

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
// b is null, because you use intent.putExtra(string, string). you should     
// use above method to get the data.
String item = b.getString("cname");
```

which will cause an NULLPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

If you used this code

```
    Intent iCreate = new Intent("silver.asw.charactersheet.CREATECHARACTER");
    iCreate.putExtra("cname",item);
    startActivity(iCreate);
```

In your second activity,you can use like this.

```
// 2nd activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.character);
TextView character = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvViewCharacter);

String item = getIntent().getExtras()..getString("cname");
character.setText(item);
}
```

Or another way you can use like this,

```
    Intent iCreate = new Intent("silver.asw.charactersheet.CREATECHARACTER");
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putString("cname", item);
    iCreate.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(iCreate);
```

In your second activity

```
/ 2nd activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.character);
TextView character = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvViewCharacter);
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String item = b.getString("cname");
character.setText(item);
}
```